# Codeigniter - autoload database and "Fatal error: Class 'CI_DB' not found" error

Tags: codeigniter

I downloaded latest Codeigniter version (2.1.4), and all I did is adding
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`
to `application/config/autoload.php`
and I have a following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'CI_DB' not found in /www/zapach_www/www/kringle/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 31`

I have this error only on one hosting machine (normal shared server), it works fine locally, or in a different server. Unfortunately I have to use specific one.

The problem appears in PHP 5.2 and 5.3

Locally I use php 5.3.

Comment: Did it work in your local machine ?

Comment: Yes, but problem has been solved. Serwer admin had to unlock eval function.